# WordPress get post filter by custom array field value

Tags: php, wordpress

I have  a custom field, which its value is an wp array..

and I am trying to get the posts filtering by this custom field, the problem is that the value its an array and my code its not working..

here it is the last try:

```
$args = array(
            'orderby' => 'title', 
            'post_type' => 'need', 
            'meta_key' =>'institution',
            'meta_value'=>  '.$institutionId.');

        $donations = get_posts($args);
```

I've tried meta_query too but it didn't work too :(

edited:

I've archived the solution I've wanted to. but I can answer my question now.. so i will post the answer when I'll be able too

Comment: how could the value retrieved from DB be an array ?

Comment: I don't know if I made myself clear but the meta_value of the meta_key institution is an array... so I think the problem is there.. since i wasn't the one who made the structure, i can't change it... :(

Comment: you need to remove the '. and .' around $institutionId. Try print_r($args) and make sure the data looks correct before you call get_posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `'.$institutionId.'` with `$institutionId` or `$institutionId[0]`